# Powering project using Moped or Motorbike

Tags: power-supply, connector

I noticed many GPS anti-theft security systems using a kind of Pin for powering them.

I want to power a 5v/12v project.

Do motorbikes generally have a female or male pin for attaching accessories?

Or do I need to hook directly to the battery?

How are these Anti-theft systems usually powered?

The following power type pin is the one see when I google.

[image: The image of the power supply]

Comment: Your question doesn't show any sign of research.

Comment: They don't have any standard connectors and the photo is too poor to work out what that connector is but it's probably supplied with a mating plug with bare wires to run wherever you like.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that these alarms provide leads to connect to the battery as @PeterJ suggests

I found this source on how to http://www.webbikeworld.com/motorcycle-alarms/cyclone-motorcycle-alarm/

> For the target 2007 Kawasaki Z1000, the following connections were made using the supplied harness and kit installation material:
>
> Red lead -- to positive terminal of battery using supplied end-connector.
>
> Black lead -- to negative terminal of battery using supplied end-connector.

Also many youtube videos suggest the same.